# Why is the output of my mutate function 26 when it should be 29?

Tags: r, tidyverse

The `minAB0` column should output as described in the `mutate()` function.

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  mutate(minAB0 = min(XD_VD+SE, value)) # why is this outputting a different number?
```

When I do it outside of the `mutate` function, it works:

```
min((data$XD_VD[1] + data$SE[1]), data$value[1]) = 29
min((data$XD_VD[2] + data$SE[2]), data$value[2]) = 36.71198
```

When I do it using **tidyverse** though, my numbers are all wrong (`minAB0 = 26` for `Sample=1` and `minAB0 = 32.98313` for `Sample=2`). Why is this happening? Does anyone get the right output when they do it themselves, and if so, how?

Here's my data:

```
data <- structure(list(Sample = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), XD_VD = c(35.9419827146857, 
35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 
35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 
35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 
35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 
35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 
32.1823275467508, 32.1823275467508, 32.1823275467508, 32.1823275467508, 
32.1823275467508, 32.1823275467508, 32.1823275467508, 32.1823275467508, 
32.1823275467508, 32.1823275467508), SE = c(0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 
0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 
0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.8008, 0.8008, 0.8008, 
0.8008, 0.8008, 0.8008, 0.8008, 0.8008, 0.8008, 0.8008), value = c(29, 
49, 44, 50, 37, 40, 50, 56, 65, 93, 87, 49, 46, 57, 39, 44, 26, 
30, 45, 44, 98, 70, 59, 70, 77, 55, 50, 33, 58, 71, 68)), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: Do you mean that each row should contain the value of `XD_VD+SE` or `value`, whichever is smaller?

Comment: Unclear why you are grouping by Sample when it sounds like you want the minimum of two items per row. For that, use `pmin` not `min`. `pmin` can take two vectors and give you the minimum for each element (ie min between first element of A and first element of B, then min between 2nd element of B and 2nd element of B, etc.), which is what you seem to want here. `min` looks at all the elements available to it (ie within each Sample) and gives the min, so it will be the same for all rows with each Sample.

Comment: When I removed `SampleID` grouping it all went to 26. I think `pmin` will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `group_by(Sample)`, what that does is have `mutate()` operate over all rows that match that condition.

So when you ask for `min(XD_VD+SE, value)`, you aren't asking for the minimum of two values, you are asking for the minimum of 42 values. You can see that's correct because all the `Sample==1` group has a `value` of 26, the lowest value, and `Sample==2` has a `value` of `32.983`, which is the lowest value of `XD_VD+SE`, which is less than the minimum value in `value` (33).

Instead of grouping by `Sample`, you can not do that, or use `pmin` as a commenter suggests, if the grouping is necessary for something else. Or you can assign each row its own group with `rowwise()`.

```
data2 <- data %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  mutate(
    minAB0 = pmin(XD_VD + SE, value)
  )
```